# Pasting...pdf docuemnt directly into Sharepoint Online M365 fails/timesout

Tags: web-part, copy-and-paste

I try to copy and paste a pdf directly from windows explorer into a text webpart in Sharepoint and it just sittings in a 'pasting...' status until the site timesout.

Any ideas why or if this is even possible?

I have ruled out proxy blocking etc

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a PDF file into a TEXT web-part. Only images are supported.

[image]

To add a PDF file into a modern page please follow this (**Use EMBED web-part**) https://www.aerieconsulting.com/blog/how-to-embed-a-pdf-in-a-modern-sharepoint-page